# Why do I keep getting AttributeError after updating my code and deleting the function that's giving me the error?

Tags: python, django, error-handling

so I keep getting AttributeError because of a function that I added and then deleted, as if there was some trace of it still in my code somehow. How can I fix it?

This is the serializer giving me the error:

```
class PedidoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   cliente = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   class Meta:
       model = Pedido
       fields = ('fecha','pizzas','telefono','email', 'cliente')
       

   def validate(self, data):
           email = data.get('email')
           telefono = data.get('telefono')

           if not email and not telefono:
               raise serializers.ValidationError("Se requiere email o telefono")
           
           elif email or telefono:
               try:
                   selected_cliente = Cliente.objects.all()
                   return ClienteSerializer(selected_cliente, many=True).data
               except Cliente.DoesNotExist:
                   return None
           else:
               return data
```

I had originally added a def get_cliente but then I just added its functions to the def validate.

The error says:

```
'PedidoSerializer' object has no attribute 'get_cliente'
```

This is the traceback:

```
django-challenge-back | Traceback (most recent call last):
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
django-challenge-back |     response = get_response(request)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
django-challenge-back |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
django-challenge-back |     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
django-challenge-back |     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
django-challenge-back |     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
django-challenge-back |     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
django-challenge-back |     raise exc
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
django-challenge-back |     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 239, in get
django-challenge-back |     return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 46, in list
django-challenge-back |     return Response(serializer.data)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 745, in data
django-challenge-back |     ret = super().data
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 246, in data
django-challenge-back |     self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 663, in to_representation
django-challenge-back |     return [
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 664, in <listcomp>
django-challenge-back |     self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 515, in to_representation
django-challenge-back |     ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
django-challenge-back |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 1869, in to_representation
django-challenge-back |     method = getattr(self.parent, self.method_name)
django-challenge-back | AttributeError: 'PedidoSerializer' object has no attribute 'get_cliente'
```

Comment: you should try searching for all occurencies of get_cliente in your editor, also see stacktrace where it is used

Comment: `cliente` is a `SerializerMethodField` and if a `method_name` is not provider then the field will default to using `get_<field_name>` https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Comment: @IainShelvington Oh, I understand now, thank you!